# Are there any disadvantages in using lazy initialization for useState?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

useState documentation says:

> If the initial state is the result of an expensive computation, you may provide a function instead, which will be executed only on the initial render

I can understand the case of an expensive computation, but what about a Number.toString():

```
useState(() => 10.toString())
```

Would there be any disadvantage in passing it in a function?

Answer (score 0):

> but what about a Number.toString():
>
> ```
> useState(() => 10.toString())
> ```
>
> > Would there be any disadvantage in passing it in a function?

If there is no benefits, it's better not to do that, since it will **reduce code readability**.

performance wise? no, it is smaller than even worth measuring; So? I wouldn't do that.